# Why do photos jump around when exporting from Muse?

Tags: website-design, adobe-muse

My company is trying to slowly move towards digital and we are in the process of learning Adobe Muse as a stepping stone to more legitimate web practices.

One issue we continue to encounter is our images moving when we export the site. The photos are usually in a text box with a text wrap applied.

My questions:

1. Why do they move?
2. Is there a way to "anchor" them in Muse?

Comment: do you have a URL to share where we can all look at resulting code?

Comment: The URL is private, but unfortunately Muse code is "bloated" which makes navigating incredibly difficult. We have a programmer on site who's attempted to sift through it (to make it compatible to our app) and he's not been able to decipher any of it.

Comment: Best of luck to your developer - we [evaluated Muse for internal use][1] and came to conclusion that it was not a good fit for commercial projects, preferring [Edge Reflow][2] instead precisely for the reason you described.  Muse generates ton of junk code and if you're going for high-fidelity match to approved creative it's a huge undertaking to clean up all that auto generated HTML, might as well just code from scratch. 


  [1]: https://www.oss-usa.com/how-adobe-muse-completely-changing-design-and-coding-web
  [2]: https://www.oss-usa.com/adobe-edge-reflow-optimizes-design-and-coding-web